# Audio file is not being copied across with Fire Monkey debug

Tags: android, audio, firemonkey

I am trying to play an audio file each time that a button is pressed in my fire monkey application.
It works in when I run the application in widows, but as soon as I try to run it on my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini it doesn't find the file.
I understand this, how ever I don't know where or how to place the file in the same folder on the Android device.

I have seen what path the Android uses to run the application by using `ShowMessage(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim);`. The path that it outputs is
`/data/data/com.embarcadero/project 1/files/`.

How do I copy my audio file to the device (or tell my RAD Studio to include this file when compiling the APK), or is there a way that I can include the audio file in the APK as I do with the images in the application?

I am using a `TMediaPlayer` to play the sound and its `filename` property to set the actual mp3 file.
I just want to note that the file plays in windows.

I am fairly new to FM development so any help with regard to the debugging on another platform will be appreciated

**Edit**

I have found a directory when searching my phones memory on the path `This PC\Galaxy S3 Mini\Phone\Android\data\com.embarcadero.VirtualPhone\files` but I still the application still says it can't find the file. I have even specified the full path. IE `MediaPlayerTones.FileName := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath +
    System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'Key.mp3';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the deployment window in the Delphi IDE (Menu: Project > Deployment), you can configure what files should be deployed to the device when your application runs.
Just be sure to choose "All configurations" first, so it is added to both debug and release mode.